# Get column number by referencing column title

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets I have a number of columns that I have given titles to in Row 1. Using a formula, I want to return the column number (i.e. 5, 6, 7, ...) for the column that has a specific title. For example: =GetColumnNumber("Account Balance").

This `GetColumnNumber()` function above doesn't actually exist, but it demonstrates what I'm trying to do.

Is there a way to achieve the same result?

I've found [this function reference](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=82712&version=static) which I've been trying to sift through.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think this will do what you want. For example if your columns are A to D,

```
=iferror(match("Account Balance",A1:D1,0),"No match")
```

returns the column number or an error message.

Thanks for pointing out that function list. It will come in handy.

Answer (score 7):

You were right on the money:

```
=COLUMN(AccountBalance)
```

Returns the column number for the named range.

You must create a named range using the Data>Named Ranges menu item and the Add a Range option in the resulting sidebar. The name can't contain spaces or other invalid characters and, when used in a function such as the one above, must be unquoted.

Comment: I just checked that and it doesn't work !! Perhaps you can explain how this solution works?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra: They've changed the way it functions in recent versions. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: You're alive !! Wow, thanks Dennis, I've learned something today.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by adding a row that contains the `formula =column()`
Then find the column number with the `vlookupfunction`.